# Can I use AMDGPU or (PRO) on AMD FX-9800p[Radeon R7]APU AMPGPU 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

Wondering if it's possible to use either the AMDGPU or AMDGPU-PRO stacks on my HP Envy m6-convertible with FX-9800p with Radeon R7(APU). This IS a GCN 1.2 chip under the name of "Bristol-Ridge". I've looked at the documentation, it's not listed, but it's newer than many of the listed chips and it's theoretically on the same silicon, also the list explains that it's not exhaustive.

I've read that there are 2 versions, one that uses Mesa/Gallium and one that doesn't.

Open to any suggestions! I'm trying to fix a screen-tearing issue, and having no sound over HDMI, Someone mentioned these drivers as possible fixes.

Comment: What driver are you currently using then? If amdgpu supports that chip, then it should be getting used by default, already.

Comment: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CARRIZO (DRM 3.1.0 / 4.4.0-71-generic, LLVM 3.8.0)  which I thought was called "radeon.si", I was under the impression that AMDGPU was a serparate open-source driver from AMD while the Gallium drivers are from the community along with the Mesa?

Comment: Also, I should note that my chip actually isn't a Carrizo, it's a Bristol-Ridge, but Ubuntu identifies it as Carrizo.

Comment: Both _radeon_ and _amdgpu_ drivers are open source and based around Gallium, in the upstream kernel/Xorg trees. The Pro version is mostly just newer version of the open source pieces, and a little additional proprietary piece. Does `lsmod` output show you are using radeon, or amdgpu?

Comment: It shows amdgpu,                        amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
amdgpu                987136  32
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
ttm                    94208  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 amdgpu

Comment: What's strange is, screenfetch was showing no GPU information until earlier this week, but I didn't install any drivers manually as far as I know.

Comment: Then you are already using the _amdgpu_ driver. It is installed by default. Since it seems it is already working for you, it's probable that the Pro version of the driver will also work. You can also install the HWE updates (`xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04` and `linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04` or signed/lowlatency variants if using those), which will give you updated drivers which may resolve some of the issues you've had.

Comment: Yes, a large part of my issue is addressed on the amdgpu Ubuntu documentation: The lack of HDMI audio which it mentions COULD be fixed with the pro variant, I'm thinking the drivers became installed when I installed Steam, that's the only sense I can make of it. I'm a little nervous about trying to install the "Pro" variant, I haven't seen anyone successfully do it on my distro (elementary OS Loki), but i think they were downloading binaries directly from AMD. Thank you for taking the time to help me, despite there being no real problem.

Comment: Steam does not install any drivers. _amdgpu_ is installed by default.

Comment: I'm sorry but I must ask you to clarify something if you can: On my older APU laptop with an A10-5750m  the output of lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
is : VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 222c
 Kernel driver in use: radeon   but on my current system it's :  VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo (rev c8)
 DeviceName: ATI EG BROADWAY
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Carrizo. Isn't the Radeon kernel driver better?